# Как лучше промоделировать ходы шахматных фигур?

Tags: c++

Только учусь, не бейте сильно.
Программа при выборе первой фигуры показывает куда она может пойти, учитывая куда может пойти слон. Он у меня по умолчанию, подскажите как промоделировать все варианты хода всех типов фигур(кроме пешок и короля). Понимаю, что у меня тут в коде, хоть все и работает, но детсад. Прошу критики, если есть время читать код.

```
 #include <iostream> //я сделал для всех фигур и слона(bishop); 
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <ctime>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <cmath> 
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int n;
        int m;
        int v, v1;
        int g, g1;
        int chooseFigure;
        char a;
        cin >> n;
        cin >> m;
        cout<<"Enter coord. first figure (vertical,gorizontal)"<<endl;
        cin>>v;
        cin>>g;
        v--;
        g--;

        cout<<"Enter coord. second figure (vertical,gorizontal)"<<endl;
        cin>>v1;
        cin>>g1;
        v1--;
        g1--;


        char array[n][m];
        cout<<"Choose type of figure: "<<endl;
        cout<<" 1 - queen \n 2 - castle \n 3 - knight \n 4 - bishop \n ";

        cin>>chooseFigure;
        if (chooseFigure==1) a = 'Q';
        if (chooseFigure==2) a = 'C';
        if (chooseFigure==3) a = 'K';
        if (chooseFigure==4) a = 'B';
        char b = char (206);
        char c = '+';
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if ((i+j)%2!=0) array[i][j]=char(178);
                else array[i][j] = char(177);
                if ((chooseFigure == 1)&&((i == v || j == g)||(abs(i - v) == abs(j - g)))) array[i][j] = c;
                if ((chooseFigure == 2)&&(i == v||j ==g)) array[i][j] = c;
                if (chooseFigure == 3){
                    if (((j+1==g)^(j-1==g))&&((i+2==v)^(i-2==v))) array[i][j] = c;
                    if (((i+1==v)^(i-1==v))&&((j+2==g)^(j-2==g))) array[i][j] = c;
                }
                if ((chooseFigure == 4)&&(abs(i - v) == abs(j - g))) array[i][j] = c;
                if ((array[i][j] == c) && (abs(i - v1) == abs(j - g1))) array[i][j] = char(254);  
            }
            array[v][g] = a;
            array[v1][g1] = b;
            cout << "\n";
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            cout<<setw(3)<<array[i][j]; }
            cout<<"\n";
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Лучше бы использовать константы вместо магических чисел (177, 178, 206).
2. Я бы создал базовый класс Фигуры, от которого унаследовал пешек, коней, слонов и т.д. Расчет возможных ходов делал бы в виртуальной функции (раз уж мы в Си++, то надо бы использовать ООП-возможности) (к тому же этим бы предовратил большое количество ифов)
3. Создал бы класс клетки, которая хранила бы координаты в шахматной нотации (E2, E4 и т.д). Указанная в (2) функция возвращала бы массив из этих клеток

(Дальше уже можно создавать ИИ, графику, звук - интереснее уже пойдет. Успехов в творчестве!)

Answer (score 1):

В своем коде Вы много используете "магические константы". И смотря на `chooseFigure == 3` думаешь, " а что это???". В этом случае правильно завести себе enum и дальше использовать его

```
enum piece { // да да, это фигуры так будут по английски.
  queen = 1,
  rook = 2, // а не castle
  knight = 3,
  bishop = 4
};
```

и теперь в коде можно будет писать `chooseFigure == knight`. Если используете новый стандарт (с++11), то можно написать даже так

```
enum class piece { // да да, это фигуры так будут по английски.
  queen = 1,
  rook = 2, // а не castle
  knight = 3,
  bishop = 4
};
```

в этом случае нужно будет объявлять так `piece chooseFigure;` и использовать так `chooseFigure == piece::knight`, но теперь компилятор будет ругаться на `chooseFigure == 3`.

---

Также очень странно выглядит то, что при запуске программа что то хочет, что бы ввели, но никак не намекает об этом пользователю - "милый мой хороший догадайся сам".

---

```
char array[n][m];
```

это так называемые "variable length array" и являются не совсем стандартной вещью. Да и использовать в с++ лучше vector.

Этот массив очень похож на просто шахматное поле. Почему тогда явно не использовать 8х8?

---

в самый конец программы лучше добавить явно `return 0;`.

---

посмотрев на портянки с `if`, возникает вопрос, а знаете ли Вы о `switch`?

---

весь код написан одной простыней. Очень хорошо выносить в отдельные маленькие функции. Легче будет писать.

---

о том, что лучше сделать отдельный класс для каждой фигуры уже писал @asianirish
В этом случае при правильном наследовании половина `if` даже не будет нужна.